# GSON JsonElement.getAsString vs. JsonElement.toString?

Tags: gson

What is the difference between `JsonElement#getAsString()` vs. `JsonElement#toString()`?

Are there situations where one should be used over the other?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html):

`getAsString()`

> convenience method to get this element as a string value.

This method accesses and returns a property of the element, i.e. the value of the element as a java `String` object.

`toString()`

> Returns a String representation of this element.

This method is the "standard" java [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method, i.e. returns a human readable representation of the element itself.

For better understanding, let me give you an example:

```java
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class GsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonPrimitive("foo");

        System.out.println(jsonElement.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());

        jsonElement = new JsonPrimitive(42);

        System.out.println(jsonElement.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());

        jsonElement = new JsonPrimitive(true);

        System.out.println(jsonElement.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());

        jsonElement = new JsonObject();
        ((JsonObject) jsonElement).addProperty("foo", "bar");
        ((JsonObject) jsonElement).addProperty("foo2", 42);

        System.out.println(jsonElement.toString());
        System.out.println(jsonElement.getAsString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"foo"
foo
42
42
true
true
{"foo":"bar","foo2":42}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
    at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:185)
```

As you can see, the output is in some cases quite similar (or even equals), but it differs in some other cases. `getAsString()` is only defined for primitive types (and arrays containing only a single primitive element) and throws an exception if called e.g. on an object. `toString()` will work on all types of `JsonElement`.

Now when should you use which method?

- If you want to print out debug information, use `toString()`
- If you know that you are dealing with a primitive type and you want to display or write the value somewhere, use `getAsString()`
- If you don't know the type or if you want to *work* with the value (i.e. do calculations), use neither. Instead check for the type of the element and use the appropriate method.

Comment: As for String type, toString() will add extra quotes, this may cuase problems.