# String.equal() returning false when it should return true

Tags: java, string, gson

I am getting JSON from a server and then parsing the JSON using GSON. I want to determine if a string element from the JSON equals another string variable. However, String.equals() returns false when it should return true.

Java Code:

```
JsonElement element = parser.parse(response.toString());

    if (element.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject data = element.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray stud = data.get("students").getAsJsonArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < stud.size(); i ++){
            String t = stud.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("StudNum").toString();
            System.out.println("t = " + t);
            if (t.equals("F02660934")){
                System.out.println("equal"); //never prints
            }
        }
    }
```

Console output:

```
t = "F02660934"
t = "002660934"
t = "002643472"
t = "002664906"
```

Is it comparing "F02660934" to F02660934, therefore returning false?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like your string has quotes. Try `t.equals("\"F02660934\"")`

Comment: That worked thanks @killjoy can you post that as the answer so you get reputation points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string contains quotes, so you need to include that in your if statement.

```
if (t.equals("\"F02660934\""))
    System.out.println("equals");
```

Though you shouldn't be using `toString()` on a `JsonElement`. Use `getAsString()` instead.

For more info see [GSON JsonElement.getAsString vs. JsonElement.toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120882)

Answer (score 0):

@killjoy recommended this in the comments, but Java was comparing `"F02660934"` to `F02660934`, reading the quotation marks as part of the string. This can be solved one of two ways if using `toString()`:

1). `t.equals("\"F02660934\"")` which causes `t` to ignore the quotation marks in `equals()`

2). `t = t.replaceAll("\"", "")` which strips the quotation marks from the string and replaces them with nothing so when `equals()` is called `t` is equivalent to `F02660934`