# Error while downloading JSON in background

Tags: java, android

I have an error in Android Studio but I don't know why

> W/System.err: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject
>           at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsString(JsonElement.java:192)
>           at com.example.whatstheweather2.MainActivity$Download$override.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:34)

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static class Download extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+strings[0]+"&APPID=***");
                URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
                request.connect();
                JsonParser jp=new JsonParser();
                JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
                JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
                String weather = rootobj.getAsString();
                Log.i("weather:",weather);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void weather(View view){
        TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String city=textView.getText().toString();
        Download download=new Download();
        download.execute(city);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON JsonElement.getAsString vs. JsonElement.toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120882/gson-jsonelement-getasstring-vs-jsonelement-tostring)

Comment: can you pl write json response that you are getting from URL?

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks, I changed `rootobj.getAsString()` to `rootobj.toString()` and now is working.