# Why am I getting the java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when using Gson.asString?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

The code is based on the following link:
[Link](https://medium.com/@hissain.khan/parsing-with-google-gson-library-in-android-kotlin-7920e26f5520)

I'm getting a run time exception:

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject` when running the following code:

```
data class Student(
    var name: String? = null,
    var address: String? = null) {
}

    class StudentDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Student> {
    
        override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): Student {
            json as JsonObject
    
            val name = json.asString
            val addressJson = json.get("address")
            val address = if (addressJson.isJsonObject) addressJson.toString() else addressJson.asString
            return Student(name, address)
        }
    }
```

the error is in:

> ```
>     val name = json.asString
> ```

which is part of *deserialize* method that is probably being called when i'm writing:

```
        val student = gSon.fromJson<Student>(json2, Student::class.java)
```

When standing over this line and pressing the ctrl + b keyboard, it takes me to JsonElement class and I see the following method:

```
public String getAsString() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

as we can see, there is only a throw statement here. But if we read the method documentation we will see that it is written there that the throw statement happen is only part of the method.

```
/**
* convenience method to get this element as a string value.
*
* @return get this element as a string value.
* @throws ClassCastException if the element is of not a {@link JsonPrimitive} and is not a valid
* string value.
* @throws IllegalStateException if the element is of the type {@link JsonArray} but contains
* more than a single element.
*/
public String getAsString() {
   ...
```

My questions are:

1. Where is the full implementation?
2. Why when I click on the ctrl + b in a code like:
   someJsonObject.asString , that I guess that it's a property, it takes me  to method with the name: `getAsString` 
   Does it mean that the get() implementation of *asString* property is: return getAsString(this)?

Comment: please Help me :(

Comment: i wish i could mate :(

Comment: You should write val name = json.get("name").asString

Comment: @Luca Pizzini, that's really helped. **But still**, even after changing the way you said, ctrl+b lead me to the same method that is part of *JsonElement* class. Can you guess why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonElement::getAsString()` only works for *json primitives*. Primitives are strings, numbers and booleans. Your `json` instance is a `JsonObject` and thus not a primitive which means there's no implementation for `getAsString()` which returns a meaningful value.

From the tutorial, you actually should do `json.get("name").asString`.

`json.get("name")` will return the `name` element which is of type `JsonPrimitive` -> a json primitive on which you can call `getAsString()`.

For further clarification, this is the content of `json`:

```json
{
   "name": "Mark",
   "address": {
        "city": "London",
        "post": "12000"
    }
 }
```

and this is the content of `json.get("name")`:

```
"Mark"
```

which then will result as the string `Mark` when `getAsString()` / `asString` is called.

---

Also see: [GSON JsonElement.getAsString vs. JsonElement.toString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34120882/gson-jsonelement-getasstring-vs-jsonelement-tostring)

---

For your question about the source code. `JsonPrimitive` is a subclass of `JsonObject`. When you navigate, the IDE only knows that it must be a `JsonObject`, but at runtime, it will see that it's actually a primitive and calls `JsonPrimitive::getAsString()`. The source for that is here: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/JsonPrimitive.java#L137-L151

This is a result of gson utilizing inheritance. If you need further assistance to understand this, I recommend reading some beginners material in object-oriented programming for Java.

Comment: Thanks,. In adition maybe you can say why ctrl+ b on **asString (from getAsString())** method leads to **getAsString** method? What does it mean *from getAsString()?

Comment: @DorVak `getAsString` is the java method. `asString` is kotlin converting the getter to a property. It's just syntactic sugar. There is no actual property/method called `asString`

Comment: thanks for the Patience. I'm new with Kotlin (a month) and it is very hard to me. you are very kind and handful. Can you please explain me, I thought that for each class in java there is a suitable class in Kotlin, in our case for JsonPrimitive, there is a *Kotlin* class with the property that returns a string. But according to your answer there isn't really such a property. I won't really find a Kotlin file for this class? I will be  happy to understand it better cause it makes me really miserable

Comment: @DorVak kotlin interoperates seamlessly with Java. There is no "Kotlin Class" for each Java class. You can directly call Java code from Kotlin. But, the general structure and naming convention for Java isn't "Kotlin Style". Thus Kotlin gives you a way to make your code calling java more "kotlin-like" and presents getters and setters as properties for example. The code `foo.asString` and `foo.getAsString()` is completely equivalent.

Comment: @DorVak See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters for documentation on how Kotlin interoperates with Java

Comment: thank you!!! BTW, where can I understand why you have wrote JsonElement::getAsString() with double :? I thought it related to reflection before you wrote it

Comment: @DorVak the notation comes from Java. `getAsString()` is a non-static method, so refering to it as `JsonElement.getAsString()` wouldn't make sense. In some Java use-cases you can refer to methods this way when needed. https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator may shed some light, but if you're getting started, it's not that relevant for your understanding of Java

Comment: java is my favorite language. I'm programing for java more than a year. Unfortunately now days all jobs regarding Android development  require knowledge in Kotlin. Thanks also for your last explanation. I think I have understand it. Thanks again!